# "Кем бы он ни был" or "кто бы он ни был" - which one to choose?

Tags: грамматика, essive, изобразительный-падеж

With structures such as the following how do we decide whether кто should be instrumental or nominative—

кем бы он ни был

OR

кто бы он ни был

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"**Кто** бы он ни был" tends to mean '**no matter who he is**' (in person or by position),

> Этот человек, **кто** бы он ни был, (даже если это сам генеральный
>   директор или рекомендованный нам Иван Иваныч) не сможет решить нашу
>   проблему.

while "**кем** бы он ни был" is close to '**whatever kind of person he is**' (e.g. by profession).

> Человеку, у которого столько родственников, оставшихся в США, не дадут
>   туристическую визу, **кем** бы он ни был (по профессии, положению в
>   обществе, какие бы достоинства у него ни нашлись).

The version with **кто** is often possible to use in either meaning while the version with **кем** is more limited in usage.

Answer (score 3):

An excellent question which in my opinion has an answer, it's just the difference is quite tricky to grasp. Any time you can ask "кем он является" instead of "кто он", you can use "кем" in your phrase as well, so

- Не стремись облапошить ближнего своего, кто бы они ни был – православный, иудей, мусульманин

and

- Не стремись облапошить ближнего своего, кем бы они ни был – православным, иудеем, мусульманином.

Are both perfectly valid, it's just that first one is more likely to encounter (just because "он явлется иудеем" is less frequent then "он иудей")

Or, say, let's consider following pair:

- Любого руководителя, кем бы они ни был, они просто скинут.
- Любого руководителя, кто бы они ни был, они просто скинут.

Again, both valid, which one to use depends on context: Любого руководителя, кем бы они ни был [отличным продажником, незаменимым управленцем, опытным кризис-менеджером], они просто скинут.

or:

Любого руководителя, кто бы они ни был [Иван Петрович, Николай Иванович или даже Пётр Алексеевич], они просто скинут.