# "Русский" and "российский"

Tags: грамматика

What is the difference between adjectives "русский" (Russian) and "российский" (Russian). In the ever-changing, myriad of names, for the Russian/ Soviet security services, down the decades, whenever "Russian" is required--"российской" is deployed eg The "All-Russia Special...."

Comment: please either use Latin alphabet or Cyrillic one - don't try to mimic Cyrillic via Latin - it doesn't help at all.

Comment: two different questions asked

Comment: Hi Robert! Welcome to Russian SE - I've closed your question because actually  you are asking completely two different things in a single post. Please, choose one you want to leave, edit the post accordingly - and it will be reopened. With this second quesion you can always create a separate post.

Comment: answers to past similar questions can be found on this site: [Русский vs Российский](https://russian.stackexchange.com/search?q=русский+российский), [Кем vs Кто 1](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14558/Кем-бы-он-ни-был-or-кто-бы-он-ни-был-which-one-to-choose), [Кем vs Кто 2](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/10610/Быть-с-именительным-падежом), [Кем vs Кто 3](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14182/case-of-complements-in-russian/)