# "Who" and "whom" in Russian

Tags: грамматика, essive, изобразительный-падеж

In "The New Penguin Russian Course", M.J. Brown (1996), a tourist in Moscow asks:

> Who was Dzherzhinsky?

using "кем" (with whom) as opposed to "кто" (who) -- Mr. Brown did not give an explanation - why would Russians say

> with-whom-was-Dzh...?

to mean

> who-was-Dzh...?

Comment: this doesn't mean 'with whom' as there's no preposition **C** (with), this is a case where Instrumental governs the verb **быть**

Comment: i'd suggest reviewing these 3 discussions [Кем/Кто бы он ни был](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14558/Кем-бы-он-ни-был-or-кто-бы-он-ни-был-which-one-to-choose), [To be with Nominative](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/10610/Быть-с-именительным-падежом), [Case of complements in Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14182/case-of-complements-in-russian/) and the topics tagged [Essive](https://russian.stackexchange.com/search?q=essive), you can see some of them in the right hand pane under Linked

Comment: guidance on how to enable another layout on the keyboard i believe one can get in some other Community or generally on the Web

Answer (score 3):

In English you could say “Dzherzhinsky was a revolutionary”, while in Russian this would be «Дзержинский был революционер*ом*» – in the Instrumental case.

Perhaps it is a little easier to see in the following sentence: “Dzherzhinsky worked *as* a politician” and «Дзержинский работал *политиком*» – in English you use a preposition, while in Russian you use a specific case for the same purpose. Going back to your example, in English with “to be” you don’t need a preposition, while in Russian you still need Instrumental with «быть» the same as with «работать».

It is hard to give an answer to “why”, that’s just how [governance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_government) works in languages: unfortunately you have to simply learn which verbs require which prepositions (in English) or prepositions/cases (in Russian).

Comment: You don't need instrumental with быть *always*, but rather in any tense that is not the present tense.